# Python3.7 subprocess outputs to terminal but does not receive SIGINT

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I have the case that a python script launches a subprocess that kills the parent while doing a self-update of the parent code.

After that the subprocess needs to start the newly updated code again and terminate itself.

That all works out except that I cannot CTRL+C anymore within the terminal I watch the output of all of that happening.

Example:

```
python3 main.py
```

1. this runs and launches a subprocess with Popen `subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'autoupdate.py'])`
2. autoupdate runs and downloads latest main.py
3. autoupdate launches new main.py `subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'main.py'])`
4. autoupdate process terminates
5. new main.py process is running fine

But from there I cannot CTRL+C anymore. It just keeps running and outputting while still in the terminal

The main.py inlcudes a signal handler

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler_sigint)
```

But this only works before the autoupdate happens.

The terminal and the new main.py process seem to be detached somehow, but the output is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to print `os.getpid()` in the recently launched python script and send the Ctrl-C signal to it with `kill -s SIGINT <pid>`.